# Pass value from `route` to template

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to pass a value from `route` to `template`. But I am not able to get the result. how to pass the value from `route` to template.

here is my try:

my route.js :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  name:"SCB"
});
```

here is my hbs file :

```
<h1>My Name is : {{name}}</h1>
```

[Live Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b0bcb36b082b6951147e2bc1b906b699?openFiles=templates.my-route.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template is mapped to the controller, not the route. To accomplish this, use the [setupController](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) function:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        controller.set('name', 'SCB');
    }
});
```

---

Another solution would be to use a controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    name: 'SCB'
});
```

Comment: It works fine. becasue I am trying to avoid `controller` since ember decided to drop off that

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Yeah, that's why I use most of the time the `setupController` function. For sake of completion I also mentioned using the controller-solution.

Comment: `controller.set('name', 'SCB');` is it only possible with `setupController` or any where in the router methods? ex: `click` any method can i set?

Comment: In most of the methods you can use `this.controller.set('name', 'SCB')`. But for the hooks which are fired before the `setupController` this is not possible (e.g. `model-hook`), because the controller is not yet loaded at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable in Controller:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  name:"SCB"
});
```

And then set it in Route:

```
this.set('controller.name', 'newName');
```

And in hbs you can access it like:

```
{{ name }}
```